# Button in GridTemplateColumn of RadGrid returning incorrect ID on button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, radgrid

I have a radgrid, with a button in a GridTemplateColumn, and when I click a button its supposed to return that rows hidden ID, but it keeps returning the incorrect ID. 
Here is my grid

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgMyAddresses" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" CssClass="table-responsive"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnNeedDataSource="rgMyAddresses_NeedDataSource"
    AllowMultiRowSelection="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" GroupingSettings-CaseSensitive="false">
    <ClientSettings AllowColumnsReorder="True" ReorderColumnsOnClient="True">
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
        <Resizing AllowColumnResize="True" AllowResizeToFit="True" ClipCellContentOnResize="False"
            EnableRealTimeResize="True" />
        <ClientEvents OnRowSelected="rowSelect" />
    </ClientSettings>
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="MemberContactsID" ClientDataKeyNames="MemberContactsID"
        CommandItemDisplay="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>

            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MemberContactsID" FilterControlAltText="Filter MemberContactsID column"
                HeaderText="MemberContactsID" UniqueName="MemberContactsID" Display="false" />

            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="60px">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnContactToEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnContactToEdit_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FirstLastName" FilterControlAltText="Filter Contact Name column" ShowFilterIcon="false"
                HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="FirstLastName" Visible="True" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="50%" />

            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Address" FilterControlAltText="Filter Member Address column" ShowFilterIcon="false"
                HeaderText="Address" UniqueName="Address" Visible="True" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
        <EditFormSettings>
            <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column" />
        </EditFormSettings>
    </MasterTableView>
    <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False" />
    <HeaderContextMenu CssClass="GridContextMenu GridContextMenu_Default" />
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

and here is button click event

```
string id;
    protected void btnContactToEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addressView.Visible = false;
        contactEditArea.Visible = true;

        foreach(GridDataItem item in rgMyAddresses.MasterTableView.Items)
        {
            Button btn = item.FindControl("btnContactToEdit") as Button;

            id = item.GetDataKeyValue("MemberContactsID").ToString();

        }
        Response.Write("Here is the ID: " + id.ToString() + "<br/>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use ItemCommand to get the DataKeyValue.

Currently your problem will be getting the last DataKeyValue due to your looping.

.aspx

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
 OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="MemberContactID">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
                     CommandName="EditButton" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Variable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("MemberContactID");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(i + "");

        ViewState["Data"] = dt;

        RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;
        RadGrid1.DataBind();

        dt.Dispose();
    }
}

protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1.DataSource = ViewState["Data"] as DataTable;
}

protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if (e.CommandName == "EditButton")
    {
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;

        // Response the DataKeyValues
        Response.Write(item.GetDataKeyValue("MemberContactID"));

    }
}
```